# Jenkins - NPM update failed

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, build

I am getting some error around `NPM update` while trying to build the code in jenkins.

All the dependencies in `package.json` file is already present in private repo.

```
Running npm update in /var/www-etc/etc/releases/source/2018012599999

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-139-generic

npm ERR! argv "/var/www-etc/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/node" "/var/www-notify/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm" "update"

npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/etc
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'etc' is not in the npm registry.
```

Comment: Show your package.json, from the given error, seems your have a dependency: `etc`, and npm failed to  fetch it from `https://registry.npmjs.org`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you use private repo, but the error said you get dependency from public repo: https://registry.npmjs.org, and I guess your network need proxy to access public network and you not set proxy for npm.

**Option 1)** specify npm registry in npm command line: 
`npm install --registry=your prive repo url`

**Option 2)** use project level .npmrc file 
1) create `.npmrc` file under your nodejs project folder (where the package.json is)
2) add below content in `.npmrc` file

```
registry = your private repo url
strict-ssl=false
// if need proxy to access private repo, comment out below two lines
// http-proxy = proxy address
// https-proxy= proxy address
```